# Ito isometry for stopping time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to prove the following: for the progressively measurable stochastic process $H(t,\omega)$ and some stopping time $\tau$ for which $\mathbb{E} \int_0^\tau H(s)^2ds < \infty$, the following are true: $$
1) \mathbb{E} \int_0^\tau H(s)dB(s)=0$$
$$2) \mathbb{E} {\left[\int_0^\tau H(s)dB(s)\right]}^2=\mathbb{E} \int_0^\tau H(s)^2ds$$
For the first one, I want to use the optional stopping theorem, but why is it justified? For the second, this looks like the Ito isometry, but I am unsure how to prove it.

Comment: Are you familiar with stochastic integrals with an infinite time horizon (i.e. $\int_0^{\infty} H(s) \, dB_s$)...?

Comment: Yes- we defined stochastic integrals for the infinite time horizon, and the finite case is generated by multiplying the integrand by the indicator function of the range you want. How can I use it?

Comment: Define an auxiliary function $G(s) := 1_{[0,\tau]}(s) H(s)$, then $$\int_0^{\tau} H(s) \, dB_s = \int_0^{\infty} G(s) \, dB_s.$$ Now you can use the properties of stochastic integrals (with infinite time horizon) to deduce both identites, e.g. the second one is a direct consequence of Itô's isometry (for stochastic integrals with infinite time horizon).